# Update Web Service Url when clicked button

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, web-services, uri

I have a web service on my c# application. I want to update webservice url when i clicked button. How can i do this.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. You want to be able to click a button and do what exactly?

Comment: Now i have an application. and i have a web service. that web service url like this: http://192.168.2.220/SabisOdemeWS/Service1.asmx?WSDL but you know this is local computer url. but i want to change this url like http://95.9.5.151/SabisOdemeWS/Service1.asmx when i clicked a button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the URL in the Reference.cs map class code behind look for the web service URL in your web.config file, we need to change this setting to Dynamic. See the article [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/wsdldynamicurl.aspx).
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The web service endpoint address is usually defined in the application's config file, but you can also specify the url in the client's constructor:

```
MyClient client = new MyClient("http://95.9.5.151/SabisOdemeWS/Service1.asmx");
```

Comment: Thank you for interesting. I will read that article and i will try MyClient client =  method
and i find this.
in C# code making a web service object than assing web service url like this object.url = 
thanks.